# Windows 8.1 batch checking if computer is part of a workgroup and changing if necessary

Tags: windows-8.1, batch-file, workgroup

I've got SYSTEMINFO | FIND /I "DOMAIN:" which displays if it's part of a Domain or Workgroup. But I'm trying to figure out how to take the result of that and if it's anything other than Company.LLC to goto :JoinWorkgroup. I would imagine it should look something like this:

```
IF SYSTEMINFO | FIND /I "DOMAIN:" NOT = "Company.LLC" THEN GOTO :JoinWorkgroup
IF SYSTEMINFO | FIND /I "DOMAIN:" = "Company.LLC" THEN GOTO :NextVerification
```

I can get IF NOT EXIST to work with directories, but can't figure out how to tie it into results of prompt utilities.

Comment: Are you confined to batch files? If not, I'd recommend going with PowerShell instead. You'll end up with cleaner files and it'll be easier to follow the logic.

Comment: Yeah, sort of am. I have a "sophisticated" batch that does a number of things in order. To call a powershell script might introduce some problems. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first look, launch next command from command line:

```
for /F "tokens=1*" %G in ('SYSTEMINFO ^| FIND /I "DOMAIN:"') do @echo %G %H
```

For use in a batch script double the percent sign `%`: change `%G` to `%%G` and `%H` to `%%H`. Then an applicable code snippet in your batch script could look as follows (retain line spacing, please):

```
set "sDomain=WORKGROUP"
for /F "tokens=1*" %%G in ('SYSTEMINFO ^| FIND /I "DOMAIN:"') do set "sDomain=%%~H"
IF "%sDomain%"=="Company.LLC" (
    GOTO :NextVerification 
) ELSE (
    GOTO :JoinWorkgroup
)
```

or, if you would prefer a solution without any auxiliary variable:

```
for /F "tokens=1*" %%G in ('SYSTEMINFO ^| FIND /I "DOMAIN:"') do ( 
  IF "%%~H"=="Company.LLC" (
      GOTO :NextVerification 
  ) ELSE (
      GOTO :JoinWorkgroup
  )
)
```

**Edit** (although accepted): use `%%~H` with the `~` [argument modifier](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to remove surrounding quotes (`"`) if any.

Resource:

- `FOR /F` [Loop command: against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- structured `IF ... ( command ) ELSE ( command )` [Conditionally perform a command](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: Worked great! And thank you for the thought out response and Resource!